# Maximal small lattice points of an elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves

The elliptic curve $-4 x^3 + 4 x^2 y + 16 x - y^3 + 9 y$ goes through $21$ integer points in the range $-9$ to $9$.  Is that the maximum?

Comment: Is that the maximum in the range $[-9,9]$?  Why make that cutoff?

Comment: [-9,9] is arbitrary.  Any non-tangent line going through two rational points on an elliptic curve will go through a third.  Multiplying by the GCD gives an elliptic curve going through more integer lattice points, for a sufficiently large lattice.  I was wondering about maxima on a small lattice, so I picked [-9,9] arbitrarily.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a longshot, but have a look at Matthew Baker and Clayton Petsche, Global discrepancy and small points on elliptic curves, http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0507228v1 and at some of the papers in the references that have titles that suggest they may be relevant to this problem.

Comment: There is a demonstration, [Elliptic Curves on a Small Lattice](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EllipticCurvesOnASmallLattice/) that gives equations for 5 elliptic curves with 21 lattice points on a [-9,9] lattice, and hundreds more with 20-15 points.